# sql nhibernate performance for loop

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have the following logic:

loop through a list of ids, get the associated entity, and for that entity, loop through another list of ids and get another entity. Code is below:

```
foreach (var docId in docIds)
{
      var doc = new EntityManager<Document>().GetById(docId);
      foreach (var tradeId in tradeIds)
      {
          var trade = new EntityManager<Trade>().GetById(tradeId);
          if (doc.Trade.TradeId != trade.TradeId)
          {
              Document newDoc = new Document(doc, trade, 0);
              new EntityManager<Document>().Add(newDoc);
          }
      }
}
```

my question is mainly about sql performance. Obviously there will be a bunch of `selects` happening, as well as some `adds`. Is this a bad way to go about doing something like this?

Should I, instead, use a `session` and get a list of all entities that match the list of ids (with 1 select statement) and then loop after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends only on my expirience. But you can test it yourselve.
If Trade entity isn't very big and count of entities wouldnt be over 1000 - reading all entities and loop after will be much preferable.
If count is more 1k - its better to call stored procedure with joining temp table, containing your ids.